# IIS apppool import fails with error message.configuration error...insufficient permissions

Tags: .net, windows, iis, webserver, devops

I am trying to export application pools from one server and then import it to newly created server.

### Step 1: Export on server1

D:>%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list apppool /config /xml > d:\apppools.xml

### Step2: Deleting duplicate apppools from xml file

Removed tags for defaultAppPool, .NetVxx appPools.

### Step3: Importing on Server2

- copied the apppools.xml file on server2
- %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add apppool /in < D:\ServerFeature\apppools.xml

this gives error

D:\ServerFeature>%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add apppool /in < D:\ServerFea
ture\apppools.xml
ERROR ( message:Configuration error
Filename: redirection.config
Line Number: 0
Description: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
. )

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Server 1 using IIS 7.5 and Server 2 using IIS 8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a config file at

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv\config\redirection.config
```

Removed the Read-only property and it worked.